# Can "unbiased" be called as one of the synonyms of "apathy"?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

Consider the sentence: "He is apathetic of whoever wins the elections", can't we say that he is not biased towards any of the election parties?

Comment: I'd say " he is apathetic about the election results" or "he doesn't care about who wins the elections". Unbiased suggests he expresses no preference for any candidate because he probably thinks they all deserve to win.

Comment: A person who doesn't care about the outcome might still have an opinion over who will win.  Also, a person's biases could be the very thing that leads to a feeling of apathy about the choices in an election.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word *bias* has a negative connotation, its meaning what I could find from google :-

*inclination or prejudice for or against one person or group, especially in a way considered to be unfair*

Someone's inclination towards something can't necessarily be called as a bias unless it is for some unfair reasons. While apathy means showing lack of interest especially emotions.

*Media's apathy towards victims of bomb blast*.

So, whether you should use them interchangeably in your sentence would depend on what you want to connotate.